# can not reach open edx studio at port 80

Tags: edx, openedx

I am totally new to open edx, I have installed open edx on ubuntu server 16.04 using the following guide:
https://github.com/regisb/openedx-docker

The lms works fine at: localhost

but the cms does not work at all, I can not reach it by any way, even from the lms when I clicked view course in studio; it says the site unreachable.

Note: the UFW is disabled because the cms is bind to port 80.

what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you try with studio port, localhost:18010? If its not working check your studio is running or not.

Comment: I tried this port also, but it did not work

Comment: Did you check the LMS/CMS running status

Comment: problem solved, I had to edit the /etc/hosts and bind the localhost Ip to the cms domain name 127.0.0.1    cms

Comment: You could also have tried http://studio.localhost